# How to quickly identify if the boxes of a triangle and a circle are overlapped

Tags: visual-c++, gpgpu

Here what I want to do is to identify the box of which triangle in a set of 2D triangles is overlapped with the box of a circle. The triangle that is not overlapped will be assigned to -1, otherwise to its own index.

The triangles’ vertices are stored in a thrust::device_vector. the d_pTriXys is the raw pointer to the vector. Each triangles’ 3 indices pointing to index of vertex array are stored in another device vector. d_pTriIndices is a raw pointer to this vector. triNum is the count of triangle.

The code is done in visual studio C++ and it works. But the performance seems to be an issue. It takes about 3.5 seconds for the case that has 2225 circles being checked with 5.5 million triangles, 2.8M vertices. It is not as fast as I wished. Does anybody have any idea to improve the algorithm for better performance?

I tried to change the register count, threadsPerBlock. right now the setting seems to be the best.

```
  // RangeAlgo.h

  struct tagXy_f
  {
     float x;
     float y;
  };


  CUDA_HOST_DEV __forceinline bool IsCircleAndTriangleBoxesSeparated(
     const tagXy_f triVertices[3], const tagXy_f &circleCen, float circleRad)
  {

     float t = min(triVertices[0].x, min(triVertices[1].x, triVertices[2].x));
     if (circleCen.x <= t - circleRad)
        return true;

     t = max(triVertices[0].x, max(triVertices[1].x, triVertices[2].x));
     if (circleCen.x >= t + circleRad)
        return true;

     t = min(triVertices[0].y, min(triVertices[1].y, triVertices[2].y));
     if (circleCen.y <= t - circleRad)
        return true;

     t = max(triVertices[0].y, max(triVertices[1].y, triVertices[2].y));
     return (circleCen.y >= t + circleRad);
  }


  // Main.cpp

  __global__ void MarkOutTrianglesKernel(const uint3 *d_pTriIndices, unsigned triNum,
     const float2 *d_pTriXys, const tagXy_f &d_circleCen, float circleRad,
     int *d_pValidTriIndices)
  {
     unsigned tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

     if (tid < triNum)
     {
        const uint3 &triInds = d_pTriIndices[tid];
        // to local variable/registers, make it faster
        const float2 triVertices[3] = { d_pTriXys[triInds.x],
        d_pTriXys[triInds.y], d_pTriXys[triInds.z] };

        bool b = IsCircleAndTriangleBoxesSeparated(reinterpret_cast<const tagXy_f *>(triVertices),
               d_circleCen, circleRad);

        d_pValidTriIndices[tid] = b ? -1 : (int)tid;
     }
  }


  void main()
  {
     // here is the sample code to check one circle with all triangles
     uint3 *d_pTriIndices;      // indices of all triangles
     unsigned triNum;           // count of triangles
     const float2 *d_pTriXys;   // all vertices of triangles
     tagXy_f d_circleCen;
     float circleRad;
     int *d_pValidTriIndices;

     ...

     int threadsPerBlock = 256;
     int blocksPerGrid = (int)((triNum + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock);

     MarkOutTrianglesKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_pTriIndices, triNum,
        d_pTriXys, d_circleCen, circleRad, d_pValidTriIndices);

     ...
  }
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have to call the kernel for each circle? Then the runtime does not seem to be too bad to me. But that's always relative and impossible to tell without knowing which hardware you are using. (Btw I would say that this is more of a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question...)

Comment: Yes, the kernel is called for each circle. my 2D triangles and circles are from rotating 3D triangles and cylinders. most probably, some cylinders have same orientation. so I changed my "Marking" function to allow multiple circles being checked after loading triangle's vertices. different arrays for the XY array of 2D triangle vertices are also used. All these improved reduced time from 5s to 2.6s.  It may still have room for improving, at least, when most cylinders's orientation is same. Computer: Inter i7-8700K CPU @ 3.7GHz, 32GB. Graphics Card: GTX1070.

Comment: So your GPU has a maximum bandwidth of 256GB/s. As an easy estimate the worst case for the number of loads of vertices is `2225*5.5m*3` and you store `2225*5.5m` markers, that is in total 440.55GB and takes on your GPU at minimum 1.72s. So you would be at 66% of maximal performance - under the assumption you have fully coalesced memory access. I think you should start investigating how often you really load the vertices and if you can save loads somehow (which is totally depends on the input). And you may be able to save many stores if you know there will be only a few overlappings per circle.